# Grab and Explode Data

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I'm sort of new to PHP, and I need some help on exploding data from a file. The file in question is: http://data.vattastic.com/vatsim-data.txt

Basically, I need to get the data under the `!CLIENTS:` section (near the bottom). With this data, I need to explode it and get the info between each `:`.

I have tried with this code, but it gives me a variable offset error (`Undefined offset: 3`)

```
$file = file("http://data.vattastic.com/vatsim-data.txt");
foreach($file as $line)
{
   $data_record = explode(":", $line);

   // grab only the data that has "ATC" in it...
   if($data_record[3] == 'ATC' && $data_record[16] != '1' && $data_record[18] != '0'&&   stristr($data_record[0],'OBS') === FALSE)
   {
        rest of code here...
   }
}
```

If someone could help me with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: use `var_dump($data_record)`. The problem is the `$data_record` doesn't have a third position

Comment: `var_dump($data_record)` is returning everything in that datafile. What's the best way to just get the stuff under the `!CLIENTS:` section?

Comment: looks like `explode(":", $line);` isn't returning what you expect.  You should test `$data_record` has the right number of elements before attempting to access them

Comment: do a `$data_record = explode("!CLIENTS", $line)` and work with `$data_record[1]` ;)

Comment: how often does this file change?

Comment: It's a data file for an online game, so it changes frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to explode rows like this:

> ; !GENERAL contains general settings

When you explode that line, you your `$data_records` looks like this:

> Array (
>       [0] => ; !GENERAL contains general settings )

Quick solution:

```
$file = file("http://data.vattastic.com/vatsim-data.txt");
foreach($file as $line)
{
   if(strpos($line,';') === 0) continue ; // this is comment. ignoring
   $data_record = explode(":", $line);
   $col_count = count($data_record);

   switch($col_count) {
     case 42: // columns qty = 42, so this is row from `clients`
      // grab only the data that has "ATC" in it...
      if($data_record[3] == 'ATC' && $data_record[16] != '1' && $data_record[18] != '0'&&   stristr($data_record[0],'OBS') === FALSE)
      {
           rest of code here...
      }
      break;
     default:
       // this is other kind of data, ignoring
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well. I'll test it out a little more and let you know.

Comment: Everything to seems to work as it should. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use regular expressions and look for `!CLIENTS:` section. This would also work in the case that the CLIENTS have more or less than 42 columns in the future

```
$file = file_get_contents ("http://data.vattastic.com/vatsim-data.txt");  
$matches = null;
preg_match ('/!CLIENTS:\s\n(.*)\n;/s' , $file, $matches );
if($matches)
{
  $client_lines = explode("\n", $matches[1]);
  foreach ($client_lines as $client)
  {
    $data_record = explode(":", $client);
    if($data_record[3] == 'ATC' && $data_record[16] != '1' && $data_record[18] != '0'&&   stristr($data_record[0],'OBS') === FALSE)
    {
      //rest of code here...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My regular expressions skills are not great but tried that and works fine but maybe there is a better REGEX to solve this

Comment: I'll keep your code in mind in case the column numbers do change. Thanks!