# Undefined Index (Laravel)

Tags: php, function, foreach, laravel

I'm bashing my head against my desk trying to figure out why this PHP code is causing this error: `Undefined index: arr`. I'm using Laravel, and this code works like gold outside of it, but inside Laravel, it's returning the undefined index error.

Here's the code:

```
function set_pilots_array($line_array)
{
    $airports = $this->airports;
    $pilots = $this->pilots;
    foreach($airports as $airport)
    {
        if($airport == $line_array[11] || $airport == $line_array[13])
        {
            if($airport == $line_array[11])
            {
                $deparr = "dep";
            }
            if($airport == $line_array[13])
            {
                $deparr = "arr";
            }
            $this->pilots[$deparr][] = array($line_array[0], $line_array[11], $line_array[13], $line_array[7], $line_array[5], $line_array[6], $line_array[8]);
        }
    }
}

function get_pilots_count()
{
    $count = count($this->pilots['dep']) + count($this->pilots['arr']);
    return $count;
}
```

This sort of goes with my other question: [Grab and Explode Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168543/grab-and-explode-data)  It's pulling the data from the data file using this code:

```
elseif($data_record[3] == "PILOT")
{
    $code_obj->set_pilots_array($data_record);
}
```

Which later does this:

```
$code_count = $code_obj->get_pilots_count();
```

Comment: Undefined index !== Undefined constant. Your title is very misleading.

Comment: are you sure about the content of `$this->pilots`? does it contain the key 'arr'?

Comment: @rdlowrey, sorry, I originally wrote this last night, and I guess it saved the title...

Comment: @rdlowreyThat's how laravel shows this specific error: index. And sometimes indeed it refers to an undefined constant.

Answer (score 6):

You do not have `$this->pilots['arr']` set. In other words, if you look at the output of `var_dump($this->pilots);`, you shall see there is no `arr` key-value pair. I suggest you this fix:

```
$count = count((isset($this->pilots['dep']) ? $this->pilots['dep'] : array())) + count((isset($this->pilots['arr']) ? $this->pilots['arr'] : array()));
```

Actually, this is not a fix - this is more like a hack. To make your code **correct** i suggest you to set the default values for those `$pilots['arr']` and `$pilots['dep']` values:

```
function set_pilots_array($line_array)
{
    $airports = $this->airports;
    $pilots = $this->pilots;

    foreach (array('dep', 'arr') as $key) 
    {
        if (!is_array($pilots[$key]) || empty($pilots[$key])) 
        {
            $pilots[$key] = array();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there is too little code to really figure out what is going on, but based on what I see:

```
if($airport == $line_array[13])
```

this condition is never being met and so `$deparr = "arr";` never happens and because of this

```
count($this->pilots['arr']);
```

is giving an undefined index error

You can easily suppress this by:

```
$count = count(@$this->pilots['dep']) + count(@$this->pilots['arr']);
```

Comment: how do you know this condition is never met? we don't know the content of `$airports` nor `$pilots`

Comment: well if that condition was met, then `$this->pilots[$deparr]` would resolve to `$this->pilots['arr']` and if it had then you would not have got `undefined index: arr` error...

Comment: that conclusion is wrong. the error occurs when the key 'arr' is not present in the associative array. completely independent from the $deparr variable.

Comment: @JanPrieser: Why don't you answer the OP with the *right* conclusion then?

Comment: @Justin: I do believe the problem is that the `arr` key is not being set because the control does not see to get into the line where it is supposed to do that `($this->pilots[$deparr][])`

Comment: @Raidenace it's weird though, if I run a var_dump, there are `arr` key arrays.

Comment: @JanPrieser: what @shybovycha did was set a default index for `pilots['arr']` as `array()` and what shybovycha helps not give out an error, and he has himself admitted that it is not a fix.- you dont really seem to understand PHP code much, do you?

Comment: @Justin, can you print out what you get in `var_dump`? BTW, you can easily suppress the notice with: `$count = count(@$this->pilots['dep']) + count(@$this->pilots['arr']);`

`

Comment: -1 The error suppression operator `@` should never be used for any reason. It is a sign of sloppy coding or a fundamental problem in the structure of your code. Avoid.

Comment: @Chris: I am aware of that general perception, Chris - even if it is not **as** bad as everyone makes it out to be. Have you ever read the PHP Internal Mailing List about the rationale why such a symbol even still exists in PHP Language?

Comment: Yep. For experienced developers, the error suppressor can have a few very limited applications -- when a better tool does not exist. The use shown here is not one of those occasions.

Comment: No, not for experienced developers alone, Chris. The god-who-be who let this so-popularly called "evil" functionality remain in the language was very much for the common developer as well. And the reason is that the language has an over-growth of notice conditions (a side effect of being open-source and patch developed), where being a loosely-typed language, instead of gracefully accepting and rectifying an internal data-state (like undefined index), it instead throws unwanted notices & warnings all over the place. (contd..)

Comment: And the average developer has to spend hours writing check-conditions for them, actually adding layers to the actual code that he needs just because the language does not take care of it for him. And many bloggers/pundits have gone on and glorified adding all those check-conditions in your code, hence the popular perception. But the language retains the @ symbol so that he can give some leverage to normal programmers who do not want to keep writing all those additional checks - which is not as bad as everyone says it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there exists a large body of theoretical work discussing the drawbacks of using `@`, whereas you're simply making an unsupported claim that it's "okay". To be clear, I am not asserting that the operator never be used, but rather, that its use case is so narrow so as to lend itself to a statement like "do not ever use this". The bottom line, anyway, is that the use of the error suppressor is **generally** (and specifically here in this answer) bad practice. Use it if you want to -- I won't, and I suggest others do not :shrug:

Comment: `To be clear, I am not asserting that the operator never be used` - then maybe I read you wrong because you entered the conversation saying `The error suppression operator @ should never be used for any reason.` - And that was the only reason I posted a lengthy comment stating why it still exists in the language, and why it is not as *bad* as some people make it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are accessing all of your indexes directly without checking if they exist first.

assume that in laravel something is causing the array to not be populated.

in order to fix this, you should either iterate through the array with a `foreach`, or do a `if(!empty($line_array[13])) {}` before accessing it.